# I am not sure how to remove duplicates during a merge sort process

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

```
`def mergeSort(array,k):
    if len(array) < 1:
        return array
    if len(array) == 1:
        return array
    if len(array) > 1:
        middle = len(array)//2
        left = array[:middle]
        right = array[middle:]

        mergeSort(left,2)
        mergeSort(right,2)

        leftcounter = 0
        rightcounter = 0
        arraycounter = 0
        while leftcounter < len(left) and rightcounter < len(right):
            if left[leftcounter] == right[rightcounter]:
                array.remove(right[rightcounter])
                array[arraycounter] == left[leftcounter]    
                leftcounter += 1
            elif left[leftcounter] > right[rightcounter]:
                array[arraycounter] = left[leftcounter]
                leftcounter += 1
            elif left[leftcounter] < right[rightcounter]:
                array[arraycounter] = right[rightcounter]
                rightcounter += 1
            arraycounter += 1
        while leftcounter < len(left):
            array[arraycounter] = left[leftcounter]
            leftcounter += 1
            arraycounter += 1
        while rightcounter < len(right):
            array[arraycounter] = right[rightcounter]
            rightcounter += 1
            arraycounter += 1
        return array[k - 1]

    array = [1,6,6,5,3,4]
    print(mergeSort(array,2))
```

I want to find the kth largest number in an array. But, I want to remove the duplicates of the array during the process of merge sorting. I have the left[leftcounter] == right[rightcounter] to check if the element are equal to each other so i can remove them but I am not sure if this is the right process.

Comment: You can try set data structure to remove duplicates. more about sets you will get here:https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's important for you to use mergesort, but if it's not then you can try this:

```py
arrayTobeSorted = [5, 3, 4, 4, 1]
noDuplicates = list(set(arrayToBeSorted))

noDuplicates
>>> [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

converting to a set then back to a list will remove duplicates *and* sort it. If for some reason that doesn't work it might be because of your version. Then you can try this:

```py
arrayTobeSorted = [5, 3, 4, 4, 1]
noDuplicates = list(set(arrayToBeSorted))
sortedArray = sorted(noDuplicates)

sortedArray
>>>[1, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you must use mergesort and don't want to convert to a set, then just put this script in the beginning of your function to remove duplicates:

```py
noDuplicates = []
for i in array:
    if i not in noDuplicates:
        noDuplicates.append(i)
```